# arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df) ... Error converting to Python objects to String/UTF8

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I wrote a simple code to read a .csv with pandas' read_csv (totally depends on pandas type inferring).  I received the error message:

```
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)"): Error converting to Python objects to String/UTF8
```

I couldn't find anything useful on the internet to troubleshoot this issue.  How do I do use the 'type' parameter in pyarrow.from_pandas(type= ...)

Thank you.

```
$ python pqwrite2.py

pyarrow version = 0.7.1

  from_size = 298877474 bytes

sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (23,28) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
id                                   int64
...
pid                                 object
mnemonic                            object
supplier_key                       float64
generic                             object
trade_name                          object
description                         object
strength                            object
form                                object
ndc                                 object
note                                object
pack_size                          float64
pack_size_text                      object
pack_type                           object
route_description                   object
...
status                              object
hidden_flag                         object
updated                            float64
created_at                          object
updated_at                          object
medid                               object



dtype: object
write_to_parquet(df, parquet_output/h_billing_codes.SNAPPY.parquet, SNAPPY) ...
ERROR:root:2017-12-13 02:22:48 EXCEPTION IN (pqwrite2.py, LINE 23 "arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)"): Error converting to Python objects to String/UTF8: Got Python object of type float but can only handle these types: str, bytes
2017-12-13 02:22:48 EXCEPTION IN (pqwrite2.py, LINE 23 "arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)"): Error converting to Python objects to String/UTF8: Got Python object of type float but can only handle these types: str, bytes
```

Comment: By default read_csv takes takes tab as a seperator. Your data seems to have a different separator.

Answer (score 3):

The full error message is

```
Error converting to Python objects to String/UTF8: Got Python object of type float but can only handle these types: str, bytes
```

It looks like there is a column containing both floating point values and strings. `pandas.read_csv` warned you about this with the message `DtypeWarning: Columns (23,28) have mixed types`. This can sometimes happen with large files. I would suggest indicating an explicit type for these problematic columns so that Arrow is fed data that is all the same type.

In a future version of Arrow, we may support yielding "Union" type columns in such cases, with some functions to enable sanitizing or converting one of the problematic types (e.g. you could say "cast everything that's not a string to a string"), but I'm not sure when this will be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message for my script.
Reading the part of the error message output by `pqwrite.py` that says

`Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
df = pd.read_csv("FILENAME.csv", low_memory=False)
arrow_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

The `low_memory=False` kwargs for `pd.read_csv` makes the error go away as it can do a better job of type inference for the `df` when it reads the file. So now the `df` does not have columns with mixed types.

I believe that `low_memory=False` may make the reading process slower and use more memory though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it caused by Pandas `read_csv` when reading large file size.  Expecting that Pandas do the **batch loading** csv into memory. When do so, chance of some 'str'(object) columns in first batch was inferred as 'numeric' type. Then the error occurred.
As pointed out by @XValidted with `low_memory = False` force Pandas to load the whole rows and make the correct inferred columns type.